# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - cannot find symbol

Tags: java, image-processing, netbeans

I have a problem with my face recognition code. Everytime I run the code there will be error of :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - cannot find symbol
symbol:   variable AppearanceRecognition
location: class AppearanceRecognition.EigenFacesRunner
at AppearanceRecognition.EigenFacesRunner.main(EigenFacesRunner.java:42)
C:\Users\Adila\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

I copy this code from somewhere but I didn't remember where so I find it very difficult for me to understand the code.

The code is:
    package AppearanceRecognition;

```
import java.net.URISyntaxException;


public class EigenFacesRunner {


private AppearanceRecognition.Visualizer visualizer;
private FaceFinder faceFinder;
EigenFacesRunner() throws URISyntaxException {
    FaceFinder faceFinder = new FaceFinder();
    Visualizer visualizer = new Visualizer(faceFinder);
    //visualizer.setOkHandler(new AppearanceRecognition.OkHandler(visualizer, faceFinder));
}

//    public static int exponent(int base, int power) {
//        int ans = -1;
//        if (power >= 0) {
//            ans = 1;
//            for (int i = 0; i < power; i++){
//                ans *= base;
//            }
//        }
//
//        return ans;
//    }
// 
//    public static int exponentRec(int base, int power) {
//        if (power == 0)
//            return 1;
//
//        return  base * exponentRec(base, power - 1);
//    }

public static void main(String [] args) throws URISyntaxException {
    int power = 0;
    int base = 3;
    //System.out.println(base + "^" + power + " equals " + exponent(base, power));
    //System.out.println(base + "^" + power + " equals " + exponentRec(base, power));

    AppearanceRecognition.Visualizer visualizer = new AppearanceRecognition.Visualizer();
    FaceFinder faceFinder = new FaceFinder();
    EigenFacesRunner runner = new EigenFacesRunner();

}
   public static void debug(String msg){
        System.out.println(msg);
    }
}
```